# Bash - get string containing spaces in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, files, wildcards

I am attempting to write a bash script that operates on each directory in a subset.
Unfortunately the path contains spaces, and I am unable to change the name.

The `for` loop insists on breaking at each space; I have tried dozens of variants, but am unable to come up with a solution.

A simplified version is below.

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod"
for file in `ls -d "$SOURCE"/201*`
do
    echo "File: $file"
done
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get every entry e.g. `/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod/2017-06-30-215735` in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no spaces in files in directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod"
cd "$SOURCE"
for file in $(ls -d ./201*)
do
    echo "File: $file"
done
```

if unsure about spaces being in the directory list or not, do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod"
cd "$SOURCE"
shopt -s nullglob
for filename in 201*;do
   if [[ ! -d "$filename" ]];then
      echo "$filename"
   fi
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

I'm not clear if you want directory file names or not, if not, this is what works.

The second is the generally preferred solution when you don't know if there are spaces or not I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this, but realised I needed `sudo` to `cd`

Comment: Probably you should quote the `cd "$SOURCE"`. And, of course, `"$filename". It is a good practice to quote expansions, specially if the do contain spaces.

Comment: `cd $SOURCE` doesn't work, you'd need `cd "$SOURCE"`. And parsing `ls` only works if the files in that directory don't contain any special characters. [Don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: thanks for the reminder on the quotes for $SOURCE. However, since I was pretty explicitly clear about the problem with using ls re spaces, and gave the preferred solution noting it's the preferred solution, it's hard to make sense of the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The least change solution is:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod"
for file in "$SOURCE"/201*
do
    echo "File: $file"
done
```

An alternative (if you have no problem on changing the positional parameters):

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Zaphod"
set -- "$SOURCE"/201*
for file; do
    echo "File: $file"
done
```

A more precise solution that avoids directories and works on file with spaces (but not newlines):

```
ls -dp "$a"/201* | grep -v '/$' | 
    while read f; do echo "File:$f"; done
```

Or a solution that works for any name, but that also may list dot-files (if the name match):

```
find "$a" -type f -name "201*" -exec echo "File: {}" \;
```